# Android Studio | Button onClick in a NavigationDrawer Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm struggling with these errors for a few days already, I tried googling it, but unfortunately I can't find any fixes for this.
I'm still a beginner in Java for Android.

So I got a NavigationDrawer with a Fragment, in that fragment i want to put a button which is clickable, but somehow it just doesn't recognize the button and some things while I've got it in my layout.

This is my code:

```js
package nl.c99.c99nlapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Souf on 21-9-2015.
 */
public class First_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View MyView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
        return MyView;

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
        Button c = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick(v);//THIS IS THE METHOD YOU WROTE ON THE ATTACHED CODE!!
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Screenshot of my project:

First_Fragment Class
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W2uG.png

Layout of first_fragment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXYPj.png

I'm getting the following errors:

- Cannot resolve symbol 'OnClickListener' (new OnClickListener)
- Method does not override method from its superclass (@Override)
- Parameter 'v' is never used. (View v)
- Method OnClick is never used (public void onClick)

Comment: write your "return MyView;" at end of onCreateView() method..

Comment: @MaheshB It already is at the end of onCreateView, but somehow it's above on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return your rootView at the end of your code, because **return means "end that method"**, so it won't continue the code below it in the same method.

Replace your code with this one:

```
package nl.c99.c99nlapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class First_Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);

        Button c = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Write your code here.
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot resolve symbol 'OnClickListener' (new OnClickListener)

Add this in your imports : `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

You just have to choose one of your views, since you have 2 I don't know why `rootView` and `MyView` then your `onClickListener()` should be :

```
Button c = (Button) MyView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your stuff here
        }
    });
```

> Parameter 'v' is never used. (View v)

Just remove this `onClick(v)`

Your coude should work if you do this :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);

    Button c = (Button) MyView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Stuff there
        }
    });
  return MyView;
}
```

### All fo your code

```
    package nl.c99.c99nlapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

/**
 * Created by Souf on 21-9-2015.
 */
public class First_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View MyView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);

    Button c = (Button) MyView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Stuff there
        }
    });
  return MyView;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, unfortunately the error didn't change and still occurs

Comment: What is myView exactly?

Comment: myView loads the layout for the class from an xml file, as you can see in the second screenshot of my post.

Comment: @S.A. Read my edit again and copy paste my code to yours.

Comment: @Thilek Yes i did that in my layout, but it does't let the errors on the class disappear.

Comment: @S.A. how about new View.OnClickListener rather then new OnClickListener ?

Comment: Click on your OnClickLister (where is red) and then alt + Enter to import the OnClickListener

Comment: @S.A. you need to import this : `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Comment: Ctrl + Space to import the OnClickListener

Comment: @S.A. from your code it looks fine.. nothing looks wrong. if you remove the onclicklistener, does your code compiles and can be deployed on a android device ? I dont see a reasons why it should not work. Maybe try  First_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener. Then   c.setOnClickListener(this);  The implement will generate a onclick method in your fragment. handle the on click inside there. But again i not sure why its not working in the first place. Also invalide and restart your android studio.

Comment: Yep, just solved it right now.
Thank you for your help!

Seems the problem was just that i had to import the OnClickListener.
I thought it was imported by default.

Comment: No problem, happy coding ;)